# Loop that will copy Data from multiple sheets to one sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I looked through the other questions, and couldn't find one to match my scenario.

I have multiple worksheets, and want to copy/paste into another Workbook/Worksheet called 'Markets'.

The next steps are to take the data out of "A1" and add those to Column A and B (respectively)

However, the copied data is currently pasting over the previous data.
My formulas also are not dragging down to the end of the data.

```
    Dim Mkts As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aDestLastRow As Long
    Dim cDestLastRow As Long
    Dim FR As Range    'first row
    Dim LR As Range    'last row
    
        'Destination Worksheet
        Set Mkts = Workbooks("Nielsen SC Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Markets")
    
        'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in Column A
        aDestLastRow = Mkts.Cells(Mkts.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in Column C
        cDestLastRow = Mkts.Cells(Mkts.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    
    'Copy 4Wk Data
        Dim Wb4 As Workbook
             Set Wb4 = Workbooks("4Wk Data.xlsx")
    
    For Each ws In Wb4.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Index <> 1 Then
    
        'Find last used row in the copy range based on data in Column A
        Dim CopyLastRow4 As Long
            CopyLastRow4 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        If .Index = 2 Then
        'Copy and Paste Data into C3
            .Range("A4:V" & CopyLastRow4).Copy Mkts.Range("C" & cDestLastRow)
        
        'Add Dates
            Set FR = Mkts.Range("A" & cDestLastRow)
            Set LR = Mkts.Range("A" & aDestLastRow)
                Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 9, 28)"
        'Add Markets
            Set FR = Mkts.Range("B" & cDestLastRow)
            Set LR = Mkts.Range("B" & aDestLastRow)
                Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 48, 13)"
        End If
        
        If .Index = 3 Then
        'Copy and Paste Data
            .Range("A4:V" & CopyLastRow4).Copy Mkts.Range("C" & cDestLastRow)

etc...
```

Comment: Where do you update `cDestLastRow`? You need to update this before you set `FR` and `LR` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot test your code, I can see only two issues:

**Issue 1** You are not updating `aDestLastRow` and `cDestLastRow` in the code provided (at least)

**Issue 2** To assign the value of `aDestLastRow` you seem to have forgotten to `Offset` the row by one.

A simple fix is to move these assignment into the loop. Another fix is to simply update the values of `aDestLastRow` and `cDestLastRow` by adding the number of copied rows, which I can see as `CopyLastRow4 - 4`, but obviously this needs to be tested. In the following code I moved the assigment lines into the code, which is the less efficient option. I hope this helps!

```
    Dim Mkts As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aDestLastRow As Long
    Dim cDestLastRow As Long
    Dim FR As Range    'first row
    Dim LR As Range    'last row
    
        'Destination Worksheet
        Set Mkts = Workbooks("Nielsen SC Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Markets")
    
    'Copy 4Wk Data
        Dim Wb4 As Workbook
             Set Wb4 = Workbooks("4Wk Data.xlsx")
    
    For Each ws In Wb4.Worksheets
        '*****Moved these lines into loop
        '*****You forgot to offset the first assignment
        'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in Column A
        aDestLastRow = Mkts.Cells(Mkts.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in Column C
        cDestLastRow = Mkts.Cells(Mkts.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        '******End of edit
        
        With ws
            If .Index <> 1 Then
    
        'Find last used row in the copy range based on data in Column A
        Dim CopyLastRow4 As Long
            CopyLastRow4 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        If .Index = 2 Then
        'Copy and Paste Data into C3
            .Range("A4:V" & CopyLastRow4).Copy Mkts.Range("C" & cDestLastRow)
        
        'Add Dates
            Set FR = Mkts.Range("A" & cDestLastRow)
            Set LR = Mkts.Range("A" & aDestLastRow)
                Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 9, 28)"
        'Add Markets
            Set FR = Mkts.Range("B" & cDestLastRow)
            Set LR = Mkts.Range("B" & aDestLastRow)
                Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 48, 13)"
        End If
        
        If .Index = 3 Then
        'Copy and Paste Data
            .Range("A4:V" & CopyLastRow4).Copy Mkts.Range("C" & cDestLastRow)
```

Comment: Forgive me, I'm still learning, the values of `aDestLastRow` and `cDestLastRow` are based on the 'Master' worksheet that does change.  When you say I'm not updating the code..?  Unfortunately, the `CopyLastRow4` is a shortened title for a entire Workbook.  The number of the copied rows is never the same.

Comment: Also what is the difference between `.End(xlUp).Row + 1` and `.End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row` please?

Comment: @CariDay *"are based on the 'Master' worksheet that does change"* - what do you mean by this? Since it does change, you have to continually update that last row value every time you paste more data to it. When you set that variable the first time, it is given a **static** value, which needs to be manually updated in each iteration of your loop - it will **not** update on it's own.

Comment: Sorry I meant the 'Master' worksheet doesn't change.  I think I'm confused.  The `aDestLastRow` is set to look at the last row of data in Column A.  The `cDestLastRow` is set to look at the last row of data in Column C, but Offset 1 Row, correct?  So I understand by placing the `aDestLastRow` and `cDestLastRow` within the Loop, the variable will be considered through each Loop.  But won't these variables then reset to the next last row of data?  (Or is that what you are saying??)

Comment: @CariDay Hi, `.Row + 1` and `.Offset(1).Row` will give you exactly the same value, but I am used to the first expression. My point was in your original code you had neither and therefore, were copying over the last used cell of column A. Please check line number 12 of your original code (count including blank lines)

Comment: **Second point**: All I did after updating that line (12) I moved lines 11 through 15 (again counting includes blank lines) inside the loop, immediately after the line `For Each ws In Wb4.Worksheets`. Now, I have 2 questions: Have you made these changes in your code? If so, has this action solved your overwriting issue?