# How to enter a formula filling in to last data row

Tags: excel, vba

Within a Macro, I am consolidating data from one workbook (4WkData) with multiple worksheets to one worksheet (Markets).

After I pull the data from `Wk4 - Sheet2`, I then have a formula to take the information on Sheet 2 - "A3" and paste the formula into "A3" and "B3" (filling to the last Data Row in Column C).

This would replicate until I loop through all the Worksheets in the 4WkData Workbook.

However, my current macro is only pasting the formula in the top row, and not down.  How do I fix this please?

```
Dim Mkts As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aDestLastRow As Long
Dim cDestLastRow As Long
Dim FR As Range    'first row
Dim LR As Range    'last row

'Destination Worksheet
    Set Mkts = Workbooks("Nielsen SC Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Markets")

'Copy 4Wk Data
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\cday\OneDrive - udfinc.com\Nielsen Scorecard\4Wk Data.xlsx"

    Dim Wb4 As Workbook
         Set Wb4 = Workbooks("4Wk Data.xlsx")

For Each ws In Wb4.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then
        
    'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in Column A
    aDestLastRow = Mkts.Cells(Mkts.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in Column C
    cDestLastRow = Mkts.Cells(Mkts.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    'Find last used row in the copy range based on data in Column A
    Dim CopyLastRow4 As Long
        CopyLastRow4 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If .Index = 2 Then
    'Copy and Paste Data into C3
        .Range("A4:V" & CopyLastRow4).Copy Mkts.Range("C" & cDestLastRow)
    
    'Add Dates
        Set FR = Mkts.Range("A3")
        Set LR = Mkts.Range("A" & cDestLastRow)
            Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 9, 28)"
    'Add Markets
        Set FR = Mkts.Range("B3")
        Set LR = Mkts.Range("B" & cDestLastRow)
            Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 48, 13)"
    End If
    
    'If .Index = 3 Then (Etc..)

        End If
    End With
Next ws
```

Comment: `Debug.Print cDestLastRow`... I don't think it is what you *think* it is. Seems like you should use `CopyLastRow4` here.

Comment: it says: 3, which means Column C, correct?  That's where the data is being pasted.

Comment: Row 3, right? And thus `Set LR = Mkts.Range("A" & cDestLastRow)` is equivalent to `Set LR = Mkts.Range("A3")`.

Comment: This is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780326/loop-the-will-copy-data-from-multiple-sheets-to-one-sheets/62780901#62780901

Comment: Anyhow, try `.Formula2` instead of `.Formula` as this might make a difference depending on the version you are using.

Comment: @BigBen I thought the '3' in `.cells(.rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row meant Column 3. The same as `.cells(.rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`.   Is that not right?

Comment: That is correct. But if you `Debug.Print cDestLastRow`, if that returns `3`, then when you think you're finding the last cell with `Set LR = Mkts.Range("A" & cDestLastRow)`, you're not actually finding the last cell.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I have office 365.  I added  `.Formula2`, but now I'm getting the application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: @BigBen so how do I find the last data row for Column C when I'm wanting the formula to fill down through Column A?

Comment: I think you meant to use `CopyLastRow4` here instead of `cDestLastRow`.

Comment: @BigBen OK, That worked, but 2 questions:  1) Why am I referencing Column A - `CopyLastRow4` if I'm trying to fill the formula down to Column C?   2) The formula filled down to 1 row past the Column C data, how to I get it to stop on the last row of data? Should I be using `.Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` instead?

Comment: You want to *determine* the last row based on column A, not column C. Column C is blank until you fill it in.

Comment: Before the Formulas, there is a Copy/Paste line to Copy the data from one Ws and paste into Column C3. `.Range("A4:V" & CopyLastRow4).Copy Mkts.Range("C" & cDestLastRow)`

Comment: @BigBen to make the formula more simplified, what if I did something like: `DataLastRowC = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` & `.Range("A3:A" &  DataLastRowC).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 9, 28)"`?  Because I need the data to stop at the last row of data in Column C

Comment: If column C is populated, then get the last row again using `DataLastRowC = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`, yes.

Comment: Yes, Column C is populated.  I changed the line to say `Set FR = Mkts.Range("A3")
            Set LR = Mkts.Range("A" & DataLastRowC)
                Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 9, 28)"`  But the formula is still populating 1 row past the end of the data in Column C.  How do I fix that?